# LDA and PCA on a dataset containing two classes

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I would like to compare the accuracies of running logistic regression on a dataset following PCA and LDA. The dataset I am using is the wisconsin cancer dataset, which contains two classes: malignant or benign tumors and 30 features. I have already conducted PCA on this data and have been able to get good accuracy scores with 10 PCAs. I know that LDA is similar to PCA. My understanding is that you calculate the mean vectors of each feature for each class, compute scatter matricies and then get the eigenvalues for the dataset. Is LDA similar to PCA in the sense that I can choose 10 LDA eigenvalues to better separate my data? I have tried LDA with scikit learn, however it has only given me one LDA back. Is this becasue I only have 2 classes, or do I need to do an addiontional step? I would like to have 10 LDAs in order to compare it with my 10 PCAs. Is this even possible?

Comment: Better fit for cross validated. Does not involve any programming. More theoretical

Answer (score 0):

Actually both LDA and PCA are linear transformation techniques: LDA is a supervised whereas PCA is unsupervised (ignores class labels). You can picture PCA as a technique that finds the directions of maximal variance.And LDA as a technique that also cares about class separability (note that here, LD 2 would be a very bad linear discriminant).Remember that LDA makes assumptions about normally distributed classes and equal class covariances (at least the multiclass version; the generalized version by Rao).